# 【Jmeter XML】How is this property generated？（in ResponseAssertion element has a dynamic prop）

Tags: xml, jmeter

Can someone tell me how **the value of the name** is generated, as shown in the figure below:

in jmx script(Response Assertion)

```xml
          <ResponseAssertion guiclass="AssertionGui" testclass="ResponseAssertion" testname="Response Assertion" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Asserion.test_strings">
              <stringProp name="50547">300</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="-1773326906">232323232323</stringProp>
            </collectionProp>
            <stringProp name="Assertion.custom_message"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Assertion.test_field">Assertion.response_code</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="Assertion.assume_success">false</boolProp>
            <intProp name="Assertion.test_type">16</intProp>
          </ResponseAssertion>
```

just the value of name

<stringProp **name="50547**">300
<stringProp **name="-1773326906"**>232323232323

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks utterly like to be a [hashcode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()), you can double check using any [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and simple [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black):

[image]